# Where do I place a counter in a recursive function?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Not sure whether to post to PSE or SO, but my question is regarding recursion.

Say I have some function MergeSort that runs recursively. If I wanted to count the number of times it splits the first half of the array, where would I place the counter? (I know I could just calculate it, but I'm trying to better understand recursion).

So, for example

```
function u = MergeSort(Array)  

%% Initializations
A = Array;
B = zeros(1,n2);    %to store first half of A
C = zeros(1,n1-n2); %to store second half of A
D = zeros(1,n1);    %to store sorted array
na = length(A);
nb = floor(0.5*na);
count1 = 0;
count2 = 0;

%% recursive part
if n1 == 1
  D = A;
  A1 = mergeSort(A(1:nb));
  A2 = mergeSort(A(nb+1:n));
```

Comment: "Questions cannot be duplicates of themselves".....damn

Answer (score 3):

```
function (sorted_array, total) =  mergesort(array) {
  if(length(array) == 1) 
  then return (array, 0); // this is not a split, don't count it

  (left, left_sum) = mergesort(lefthalf);
  (right, right_sum) = mergesort(righthalf);

  result_array = merge(left, right);

  return (result_array, 1 + left_sum + right_sum); // this is a split, add 1
}
```

This won't just count the splits in the first half, but you could call it only on the first half.  You could change it to count all of the function calls by changing the 0 to a 1.

The cool thing about this (and recursion in general) is that it's practically just restating the definition of what you want to calculate.  If we're returning from a branch, what's the definition of the total number of branches from us on down?  One for us, added to however many are on the left and on the right.  If I'm on the bottom and I'm returning, how many branches from us on down?  Zero.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is pass the counter as an argument to the recursive function itself, similar to the following:

```
func foo(bar, acc) {
    print bar;
    print acc;
    foo(bar+1, acc+1);
}
```

Then when you initially call the function, you can do so as follows:

```
foo(bar, 0);
```

There is obviously a little bit more to it than this (you'll probably want the function to do something more than just print the current variable, and you'll likely also need to make sure it has an end case), but hopefully the basic idea comes across. I recommend reading up about pattern matching, folding, and tail recursion can be of great assistance in understanding counters and accumulations, I think. To anecdotally explain how it can be helpful, I've recently spent a lot of time with [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)), which utilizes recursion and tail calls very heavily (where there might not be counters utilized directly within a function, but effectively do the same thing via using said tail calls to a point where the list is empty.

Comment: Also, it's simple to keep clean if the calling code shouldn't need to know about the counter: `func foo_public(bar) { foo(bar, 0); }`